# Reading in image files from a folder indexed with numeric name tags using python

Tags: python, path

I am trying to read in a series of images from a folder using python. The images represent small pieces of larger image that has been split into a grid and are indexed using "imagename_row_column.jpg" (i.e. img_0_1.jpg). My current code (pasted below) is having trouble with the column index and is counting numbers 10 and above in the incorrect order. For example instead of reading in like (img_0, img_0_1, img_0_2,...img_0_9, img_0_10...) I am getting (img_0, img_0_10, img_0_11, img_0_1, img_0_2...) Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
# Get images from folder
path1 = r'C:\Users\user_\Desktop\Test\IMG_Scan'
images = []
mylist = os.listdir(path1)
for img in mylist:
    curimg = cv2.imread(f'{path1}/{img}')
    images.append(curimg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"img_0_10" < "img_0_2" by string comparison.
Try custom sorting your files before iterating:

```
mylist = sorted(os.listdir(path1), key=lambda x: list(map(int, x.split("_")[1:])))
```